# Why is the Trust Region Policy Optimization a On-policy algorithm?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

I'm wondering why is the Trust Region Policy Optimization a On-policy algorithm?

In my opinion, in TRPO, we samples by the old policy and update the new policy and apply the importance sampling to correct the bias. Thus, it is more like a off-policy algorithm. 
But recently, I read a [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1706.01905) which said:

> In contrast to off-policy algorithms, on-policy methods require
>   updating function approximatorsaccording to the currently followed
>   policy.   In particular, we will consider Trust Region
>   PolicyOptimization, an extension of traditional policy gradient
>   methods  using the natural gradient direction.

Does any point I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key feature of *on-policy* methods is that they must use the estimated policy in order to interact with the environment. In the case of Trust Region Policy Optimization, effectively it adquires samples (i.e., interact with the environment) using the current policy, then updates the policy and uses the new policy estimation in the next iteration.

So, the algorithm is using the estimated policy during the learning process, which is the definition of *on-policy* methods.

Comment: So, is the PPO algorithm on-policy, too?

Comment: Yes, it is also on-policy.